# Template specialization 'on the fly'

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Let's suppose I have an empty templatized struct foo

```
template <typename T> struct foo {};
```

And a macro that specializes it

```
#define SPECIALIZE(class_name) \
template <> \
struct foo<class_name> { \
    static const std::string value; \
}; \
const std::string foo<class_name>::value = #class_name;
```

I'd like to have a method that would print the name of the class it has as a template parameter. Normally, I'd do this way:

```
template <typename T>
void print() {
    std::cout << foo<T>::value << std::endl;
}

SPECIALIZE(std::vector<int>)
int main() {
    print<std::vector<int>>();
    return 0;
}
```

However, I find it quite annoying and error-prone to have to record the class explicitly, as you have to make sure the macro is called exactly one time.

I would like to do something like that:

```
template <typename T>
void print() {
    if (notdefined(foo<T>::value)) {
        SPECIALIZE(T)
    }
    std::cout << foo<T>::value << std::endl;
}
```

which is of course not possible this way.

Do you have an idea on how I could achieve that ?

Comment: What's the purpose of doing so?

Comment: @NickyC I am writing a networking library and need a way to identify a class. I cannot use RTTI because I need it to be consistent over different compilers

Comment: @Maliafo identify it how exactly? For what purpose? I've written networking libraries and haven't had to resort to things like this.

Comment: This won't work for two reasons -- first, you'd *need* to have macros all the way until the specialization, other wise you'll end up with `"T"`, not `"std::vector<int>"`. But even then, this would break at the first appearance of a typedef. I second Remy: what exactly do you need your custom RTTI to achieve? Do you really need the type's name as a string, or is any way of distinguishing them OK?

Comment: I never wrote networking libraries ;), but still I am puzzled what would be the purpose of doing this. Once you have an object that you can pass to your `print` you already "know" its type. How does it help being able to print its name? You are kind of rebuilding `typeid(T).name`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I need to uniquely identify classes so that I can serialize them, send them over the network be able to know what was the class. Of course, I am not going to send the raw string, much more probably its hash.

Comment: @tobi303 Yeah I know, but the problem with typeid(T).name is that it's not portable

Comment: @Quentin Ye, I forgot that there would just be 'T' in that case :/

Comment: I might be wrong, but afaik `std::type_index` as well as `typeid(T).hash_code` are portable

Comment: @tobi303 type_index is only a wrapper around type_info which is itself implementation dependent. Reading through the documentation of typeid(T).hash_code [http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/hash_code] tells you that "the value can also change between invocations of the same program", which is kind of awfull for me

Comment: @Maliafo yep I was reading a bit and came to the conclusion that my last comment indeed was wrong. However, as I understood, `type_index` is meant to give you a starting point to build your own portable way without resorting to writing out all types explicitly that you want to identify. Though I might be completely off, no expert on this, just curious ;)

Comment: sorry for too chatty comments, imho we have a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you should better ask for the actual problem you are trying to solve instead of asking to fix something that maybe isnt the solution

Comment: @Maliafo you don't need to identify classes in this manner in order to serialize them. There are tons of different ways to serialize classes.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd do this by defining the concept of a `networking_traits` template specialisation that contains any information you need (re serialisation, creation, parsing, naming etc)

simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

//
// define the concept of a getting a type's universal name
// in terms of a networking_traits<> template class specialisation

template<class T> struct networking_traits;

template<class T>
constexpr decltype(auto) get_universal_name()
{
    auto traits = networking_traits<T>();
    return traits.universal_name();
}


// some object...
struct ObjectA
{
};

// define a traits object for it
template<> struct networking_traits<ObjectA>
{
    constexpr auto universal_name() const { return "ObjectA"; }
};


// some other object
struct ObjectB
{
};

// define another traits object - note the different (but compatible) type
// of the universal_name return type
template<> struct networking_traits<ObjectB>
{
    static const std::string& universal_name() { 
        static const auto s = std::string("ObjectB");
        return s;
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::cout << get_universal_name<ObjectA>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << get_universal_name<ObjectB>() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is having a template parameter being a string.
Unfortunately there are two problems with this

1. This was explicitly forbidden "just because"
2. Apparently there is a workaround using heavy template trickery in C++11

the serious problem is actually 2, as it means that probably C++ will never get anything reasonable in this area (for some strange reasons in C++ if an horribly complex half-working and logically broken solution exists using template metaprogramming then no sensible solution will be looked for).

My suggestion is simply to add an explicit member function returning a `const char *`:

```
struct Protocol {
    virtual const char *name() const = 0;
};

struct TCP : Protocol {
    const char *name() const { return "TCP"; }
    ...
};
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if you want to send an `std::pair`, you can't, because there is no 'name' method, that's why I came up with the external way of doing so. :/